# Empty CDC scans on highly active SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

We have a SQL Server which has highly active databases which will have number of transactions in an hour. CDC is enabled on this database to carry forward the committed changes to another server. But recently we see that the changes were not reflecting on the target server. There are no errors in the dm_cdc_errors table and also the log_scan_sessions is also returning all empty scans. I mean the empty_scan_count is around 3500. That means that the  capture job is running fine and it is scanning the log for any changes.

I even did an update on a table and queried the corresponding CT table but no records were popped up there. Is there any other setting/configuration that I need to check ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if any table is enabled for cdc. You can query sys.tables dmv.

I suspect db is enabled for cdc but no tables are configured for cdc that might be the reason cdc couldn't fetch transactions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a job which runs to read the log and populate the CDC CT tables. Sometimes it can stop working without throwing an error. The solution is to manually stop and re-start it again. For this you *must* use the provided system stored procedures [sys.sp_cdc_stop_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-stop-job-transact-sql) and [sys.sp_cdc_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-start-job-transact-sql).

If they haven't been down for too long, less than your clean-up interval, you shouldn't have any data loss.